# Bind SOMETIMES null value with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, null

There is only one record in my database, and the "action_taken" column is set to NULL.  How the hell do I get PDO to find it???

If I type the query directly into SQL it works as expected.

Note: This is just a test script to illustrate my problem.  Most the time the value passed will be a string, but occasionally the value will be NULL.

```
include ('include/mysql.php');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM returns WHERE action_taken = :action';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$param = null;
$sth->bindValue(':action', $param, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
if ($sth->rowCount())
    {
    echo 'FOUND YOU!';
    }
else
    {
    echo 'NOOOO :(';
    }
```

Comment: Your where clause needs to look like `action_taken IS NULL` , `action_taken = null` is not valid.

Comment: you can't test null for equality. NOTHING can EVER be equal (or unequal) to null. null is poison and contagious. any operation involving null values makes the entire operation become null as well.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I assumed PDO would have taken care of this for me.  Means I need to add checks on every parameter for NULL values and then rewrite the query/bind the parameters differently for each case.  Massively inconvenient :(

Comment: Would you recommend changing the database so the default values are "" rather than NULL?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically, you can't say "equal to null".  It always has to be `IS` null:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM returns WHERE action_taken IS :action';
```

You'd be better off not using `NULL` at all, if at all possible.

Comment: What if it's not null?

Comment: In the context of the question asked there is only a check to see if it matches NULL.  I suggested not using `NULL` because then `=` can be used instead